# how to crawl every pages from the same head url?

Tags: r, xml, curl, web-crawler, rvest

i want to crawl every pages from the same head url

ex:"http://www.htc.com/tw/XXXXXXX"
Hanv any way to do?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work since most web servers have directory listing disabled.
There is no way to crawl every page. However, you can crawl every sub page which is linked on the main page. You could for example create an array of all links found on that site, and filter those with the same domain name. But this won't find directory's which aren't linked anywhere.